# Updating Password based On Old Password . SQLite database android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am Trying to Change/Update Password Based on Old password saved in the SQLite database, but it is not working

**Here is Model class:**

```
public class SyncDownPasswordsTable {

public static final String SYNCDOWN_PASSWORDS_TABLE_NAME = "SyncDownPasswordsTable";
public static final String KEY_USER_ID = "userId";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

private String userId , password;

public SyncDownPasswordsTable(String userId, String password) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.password = password;
}

public SyncDownPasswordsTable() {
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public static String CreateSyncDownPasswordTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + SYNCDOWN_PASSWORDS_TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
        " " + KEY_USER_ID + " integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT," +
        " " + KEY_PASSWORD + " text" + ")";
}
```

**and method inside Database Handler class.**

```
public int updateSyncDownPassword(SyncDownPasswordsTable synDPTable) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SyncDownPasswordsTable.KEY_PASSWORD, synDPTable.getPassword());

    // updating row
    return db.update(SyncDownPasswordsTable.SYNCDOWN_PASSWORDS_TABLE_NAME, values, SyncDownPasswordsTable.KEY_USER_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(synDPTable.getUserId())});
}
```

**and method call inside UpdatePassword Dialog.**

```
if (v == updateButton) {
        if (!(oldPass.equals(savedPass) && newPass.equals(confirmPass))) {

            toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Passwords didn't match , check Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            oldPassword.setText("");
            newPassword.setText("");
            confirmPassword.setText("");
        } else {

            SyncDownPasswordsTable syncDownPasswordsTable = new SyncDownPasswordsTable();
            syncDownPasswordsTable.setUserId(syncDownPasswordsTable.getUserId());
            syncDownPasswordsTable.setPassword(newPass);
            int update = dbHandler.updateSyncDownPassword(syncDownPasswordsTable);

            if (update > 0) {
                toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Password Updated Successfully .", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
                dismiss();
            } else {
                toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
                dismiss();
            }
        }
    } else {
        dismiss();
```

Comment: It only executes Else satement . each time , help .

Comment: How about debugging it step by step, and see why it it does the `else`!

Comment: @lionscribe  tried , no solution , but thanks

Comment: When going step by step, check what values for oldPass, savedPass and  newPass, confirmPass, and what doesn't match.

Comment: @ lionscribe  values are same which i gave as an input . check out update method .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are getting/passing a userid of "" rather than the current userid.

That is

```
SyncDownPasswordsTable syncDownPasswordsTable = new SyncDownPasswordsTable();
```

Creates a new SyncDownPasswordsTable object, with no values/properties set.

This then followed by

```
syncDownPasswordsTable.setUserId(syncDownPasswordsTable.getUserId());
```

Which sets the userid to the existing unset userid as obtained by `syncDownPasswordsTable.getUserId();`

In short it does nothing with values.

So you need to do something along the lines of :-

```
syncDownPasswordsTable.setUserId(a_valid_existing_current_userid);
```

Where **a_valid_existing_current_userid** is the userid that you want to update.

Comment: To test you could set the value to a specific known valid value e.g. `syncDownPasswordsTable.setUserId("Fred");` (if Fred is a valid, existing userid).

Comment: @RashidKalhoro that's good. if the answer answered the question then please tick it as the asnwer.

Comment: @ MikeT Done Mike .